# Is there a difference between Typescript `interface X extends Y` and `type X = X & Y`?

Tags: typescript, interface, extends, type-alias

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgggZQKJQLxQN5Wz3B6PKOAGQQHkoB1MgJQGkEoAxWqAInmTaMYEkA7YBABOAMwCGAYwgAoXACNxAZwgAudopVsZAXxkyAloJETpUMjABSSAMIAVAPpwAjFAgAPIfwAmS2IhQMORwwYQB7MDh1NlCIuG09GVBIcytbRzgAJjRMYOxYyOiC+N0oADJ-ZH1JMP4lYChxZ3ULa3snV3QMYqLwyLYAGihNNQ1lCDY9GrqG8UyWtPasnO6+qPZiweHx6JHJmSA)

See this code:

```
type BASE = {          // ALSO WORKS FOR "BASE" AS Interface
    base: "base"
}

interface OBJECT_A1 extends BASE {
    propA: "propA"
}

type OBJECT_A2 = {
    propA: "propA"
} & BASE

const a1: OBJECT_A1 = {propA: "propA", base: "base"}
const a2: OBJECT_A2 = {propA: "propA", base: "base"}
```

It works fine. Both approaches seem to work.

Is there any practical difference between "extending" an object by using `interface X extends Y` and `type X = X & Y` ? When should I use one over the other?